# Search bar in bing maps app / Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I wondering if Bing Maps have searchbar on Windows Phone like Google Maps on Android. Something like this:

[image]

I just need searching for specific location. When I input name of country, town or street i just want that app show this place on map.

Comment: No, the Bing Maps control does not have that built-in, you'll have to add it yourself.

Comment: But how? I'm beginner in wp7 programing, do you have any tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not solve the problem mean try this:

```
       private void getAddress()
       {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city=%22new%20york%22&format=json"));
       }



        void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("e.Result==>" + e.Result);
        }
```

Just call the getAddress() on click event.. You will get the json data as out put..!!